# Отобразить имя и фамилию на странице

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api, css, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отобразить Имя и Фамилию (или другие данные `VK API`) на странице синим цветом (`CSS`), при помощи `users.get`, а то как ни пытаюсь - не получается.

Comment: как пытались?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чем собственно сложность то?)

```
<div style='color:blue;'><div>

response = users.get(uids='1,2,3,4');
for(index in response['response']){
$('div').append(response['response'][index]['first_name']+'<br>');
}
```

Comment: ну ты полный исходник дай
с <head> и <body>
и я проверю

Comment: а то не могу разобраться что куда вставлять

Comment: может мне за тебя весь проект сделать?)

Comment: В head'е подключаешь библиотеку jQuery и описанный выше скрипт. 
response = users.get(uids='1,2,3,4');
for(index in response['response']){
$('.out').append(response['response'][index]['first_name']+'<br>');
}
в body:
<div class="out"><div>

в файле стилей:
.out{ color: blue;} 

Так понятнее?